# HBase REST API checkAndPut or checkAndDelete

Tags: hbase

I am using HBase REST api in c#.How can i implement the checkAndPut or checkAndDelete in HBase REST API...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it was added in [HBASE-4720](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-4720).